# In Android, view previously opened web page when offline

Tags: wi-fi, firefox-for-android, browser

On a laptop, I can open some tabs in the browser, switch to another window, disconnect from the network, return to the browser window, and the tabs are still there.

On Android, when I return to the browser, the contents of the tabs is lost (well, usually -- sometimes it's still there). Is there a simple way to have the pages cached as it would be on PC?

Namely, on the phone I open a web page in Chrome, read half of it, close my phone (or let it turn off the screen after some seconds of inactivity) or use some another app (such as make a call), go out of home (no wifi), open my phone, return to the Chrome window, and I would expect to see the same page (and the same tabs), even if I am offline by that moment.

But the page is gone and says it won't be shown without connection.

I know I can use other apps to save the pages in a folder and open them from that folder.

However, can't it work just transparently without the need to explicitly save the pages and explicitly open them? Open a page, do something else, return to the browser window, and see the same page.

I am OK using any browser (Firfox? Opera?) that can do this.

Comment: Chrome has a flag for saving webpages. Can't remember offhand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Sleipnir browser for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.fenrir.android.sleipnir) has an option for making all tabs remain loaded even when the phone is offline. No need to specifically save a tab or do anything special to make your tabs available when you're offline. I'm not sure about the details, but it seems to fit your needs. The Mac/Windows versions of Sleipnir has [much cooler features](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/sleipnir-site-updates.html) than the Android version, but it is still worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Via Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mark.via.gp) from Play Store.

Comment: Hello. Please do mention the instructions that one can use to achieve the objective in question. If the app usage is trivial than sometimes these instructions can be skipped. In this case, it doesn't seem to be trivial enough.

Answer (score -1):

On your laptop, you cache images and websites to disk while on Android you only cache in memory. Meaning that when the app quits (or the system determines that it can quit the app automatically), the page is removed from your device.

[Opera’s browsers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6928237143520558692) does indeed allow you to save any webpage for later offline use. You must, however, choose to save it while you are online.

Many reading-list apps also does it if you want to explore other options.

Comment: What is your source for saying that Android browsers cannot cache pages to disk? // I distinctly know otherwise

Comment: This is not true. All browsers, chrome, firefox, brave, duckduckgo, all remember open tabs